# How to correctly lock async generators?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, generator, python-asyncio

I am trying to use an async generator as a wrapper for a shared connection

```
async def mygen():
    await init()
    connection = await open_connection()
    while True:
        data = yield
        await connection.send(data)


shared_gen = None

async def send_data(data):
    global shared_gen
    if not shared_gen:
        shared_gen = mygen()
        await shared_gen.asend(None)
    await shared_gen.asend(data)
```

Is the above code safe from race conditions? Is it possible for two `asend`s to execute concurrently or the second one will block implicitly until the generator is ready in the yield step? Assume `connection.send` is not concurrency safe.

**Update**:

Wrote a wrapper to help use safely.

```
class Locked:
    def __init__(self, resource):
        self._resource = resource
        self._lock = asyncio.Lock()

    @contextlib.asynccontextmanager
    async def lock(self):
        async with self._lock:
            yield self._resource

async def send_data(locked_gen, data):
    async with locked_gen.lock() as gen:
        await gen.asend(data)


async def main():
    gen = mygen()
    await gen.asend(None)
    locked_gen = Locked(gen)
    ...
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You seem to be asking for a functional code review, which is off-topic here.

Comment: @Prune How is this asking for a code review, it clearly provides pseudo-code and has a clear question.

Comment: @balki The answer to your question is no, Python doesn't allow it. But it will not just block the second `asend`, it will raise a `RuntimeError`. See [this test code](https://pastebin.com/SRQgs8jg).

Comment: And if you want to block instead, you'll need an explicit lock around the await of `asend`. I'll post the code once the answer is reopened.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks. Yes. Looks like async gen usually needs a lock when used by multiple async paths.

Comment: I see a race condition / potential AttributeError for `global shared_gen` between the two `await shared_gen.asend()`.  You could get a `await None.asend(data)` if somebody sets the global to None while the `send_data()` coroutine is running.  It would be better to pass in the value of `shared_gen` as a parameter to the function.

Comment: @ScottP. Asyncio is single-threaded, so a race condition involving access to the global is not possible.

Comment: Another coro / task can modify the global between awaits; so yes, it is a race condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for two `asends` to execute concurrently or the second one will block implicitly until the generator is ready in the yield step?

It is not possible for `asend` to be called concurrently, but trying to do so doesn't result in blocking. Instead, the second one will raise a `RuntimeError`, as demonstrated by the following example:

```
import asyncio
 
async def gen():
    while True:
        yield
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    ait = gen()
    await ait.asend(None)  # start the generator
    async def send():
        print('sending')
        await ait.asend(42)
    await asyncio.gather(send(), send())
 
asyncio.run(main())
```

To make the send block until the previous one finishes, you need an explicit lock around the await of `asend`:

```
async def main():
    ait = gen()
    await ait.asend(None)
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    async def send():
        async with lock:
            print('sending')
            await ait.asend(42)
    await asyncio.gather(send(), send())
```